# jQuery check/uncheck all inside gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my user control, there is a gridview. I want to select/unselect all checkboxs inside the gridview  using the header checkbox. So I implement it using jQuery.

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
    $('#<%=gridView.ClientID %> >tbody >tr >td >input:checkbox').attr('checked', chk.checked);
}
```

In my headertemplate of the gridview I put this one

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server"  OnClick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);"/>
```

It works well.
But when another developer puts my user control in the aspx **twice**,
it does not work well.

Whenever I check the 1st or the 2nd  Gridview's header checkbox, **only the 2nd** GridViews's checkboxes are check or uncheck.

It never check the first GridView's checkboxes even when I check the 1st Gridview's header checkbox.

What kind of modification do I need ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `closest()` method:

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
    $(chk).closest('table >tbody >tr >td >input:checkbox').attr('checked', chk.checked);
}
```

From jquery's documentation: "Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."

EDIT: I'm not pretty sure if it will work like that. If not, you could try:

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
    $(chk).closest('table').find('>tbody >tr >td >input:checkbox').attr('checked', chk.checked);
}
```

Hope it helps.